# SQL state: 22P02 invalid input syntax for integer: "f"

Tags: postgresql

I'm facing issues on running this function. I couldn't find the reason why. I would appreciate a lot for any hint. I'm trying to use this function to make an `INSERT`.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION multas.insertar_cuota(cant_cuota int,fecha_multa date,importe_total int, cod_multa int,cuota int, nro_cuota int, financiado int) 
RETURNS VOID AS

$BODY$
DECLARE 
ultima_cuota int;
diferencia int;
num_cuota int;
venc date;
BEGIN 
IF (financiado=1) 
THEN PERFORM cuota= ROUND(importe_total/cant_cuota)
,diferencia=importe_total-(cuota*cant_cuota)
,ultima_cuota=cuota+diferencia;

WHILE nro_cuota<(cant_cuota+1)
LOOP
IF(nro_cuota=cant_cuota)
THEN cuota=ultima_cuota;

 ELSE 
cuota=cuota;
END IF;
BEGIN
num_cuota=(nro_cuota=(nro_cuota+1));
venc=fijarvencimiento(fecha_multa);
INSERT INTO multas.cuotas_multas(id_cuota,nro_cuota,fecha_vto,importe_vto,pagado)
VALUES(cod_multa,num_cuota,venc,cuota,NULL);
END;

END LOOP;
END IF;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is complaining that you are trying to use "f" (false) where it expecting an integer.

I suspect this line is responsible

`num_cuota=(nro_cuota=(nro_cuota+1));`

I don't know what you think it is doing, but it is inspecting whether `nro_cuota = (nro_cuota+1)` which is of course false.

Also, use `:=` for assignment - it makes code clearer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are correct, i make work the function, thanks a lot!!!

Comment: What is the difference between `:=` and `=`